# How to use lapply to transform specific values in a list of dataframes

Tags: r, lapply, tidyverse

I'm looking for help to transform a `for` loop into an `lapply` or similar function.

I have a `list` of similar `data.frame`s, each containing

- an indicator column ('a')
- a  value column ('b')

I want to invert the values in column b for each data frame, but only for specific indicators. For example, invert all values in 'b' that have an indicator of 2 in column a.

Here are some sample data:

```
x = data.frame(a = c(1, 2, 3, 2),  b = (seq(from = .1, to = 1, by = .25)))
y = data.frame(a = c(1, 2, 3, 2),  b = (seq(from = 1, to = .1, by = -.25)))
my_list <- list(x = , y = y)

my_list
$x
  a    b
1 1 0.10
2 2 0.35
3 3 0.60
4 2 0.85

$y
  a    b
1 1 1.00
2 2 0.75
3 3 0.50
4 2 0.25
```

My desired output looks like this:

```
my_list
$x
  a    b
1 1 0.10
2 2 0.65
3 3 0.60
4 2 0.15

$y
  a    b
1 1 1.00
2 2 0.25
3 3 0.50
4 2 0.75
```

I can achieve the desired output with the following for loop.

```
for(i in 1:length(my_list)){
    my_list[[i]][my_list[[i]]['a'] == 2, 'b'] <-
        1 - my_list[[i]][my_list[[i]]['a'] == 2, 'b']
}
```

BUT. When I try to roll this into lapply form like so:

```
    invertfun <- function(inputDF){
    inputDF[inputDF['a'] == 2, 'b'] <- 1 - inputDF[inputDF['a'] == 2, 'b']
    }
resultList <- lapply(X = my_list, FUN = invertfun)
```

I get a list with only the inverted values:

```
resultList
$x
[1] 0.65 0.15

$y
[1] 0.25 0.75
```

What am I missing here? I've tried to apply (pun intended) the insights from:

[how to use lapply instead of a for loop, to perform a calculation on a list of dataframes in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46123443/how-to-use-lapply-instead-of-a-for-loop-to-perform-a-calculation-on-a-list-of-d)

I'd appreciate any insights or alternative solutions. I'm trying to take my R skills to the next level and `apply` and similar functions seem to be the key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `lapply` to loop over each list and change the `b` column based on value in `a` column.

```
my_list[] <- lapply(my_list, function(x) transform(x, b = ifelse(a==2, 1-b, b)))

my_list
#[[1]]
#  a    b
#1 1 0.10
#2 2 0.65
#3 3 0.60
#4 2 0.15

#[[2]]
#  a    b
#1 1 1.00
#2 2 0.25
#3 3 0.50
#4 2 0.75
```

---

The same could be done using `map` from `purrr`

```
library(purrr)
map(my_list, function(x) transform(x, b = ifelse(a==2, 1-b, b)))
```

Comment: Thanks Ronak! I also got some insight into why my original approach was not working that I will share in another answer.

Answer (score 0):

See Ronak's answer above for a fairly elegant solution using `transform()` or `map()`, but for those who are following in my footsteps, my original solution would work if I added a line in the custom function to return the full data frame like so:

```
invertfun <- function(inputDF){
    inputDF[inputDF['a'] == 2, 'b'] <- 1 - inputDF[inputDF['a'] == 2, 'b']
return(inputDF)    
}

resultList <- lapply(X = my_list, FUN = invertfun)
```

UPDATE - On further testing, this solution throws an `Error in x[[jj]][iseq] <- vjj : replacement has length zero` when the desired 'a' value doesn't exist in one of the data frames. So best not to go down this road and use the accepted answer above.

Answer (score 0):

`lapply` is typically not the best way to iteratively modify a `list`. `lapply` is going to generate a loop internally in any case, so usually easier to read if you do something more explicit:

```
for (i in seq_along(my_list)) {
    my_list[[i]] <- within(my_list[[i]], {
        b[a==2] <- 1 - b[a==2]
    })}
```

If we replace `within` with `with` in the example above, we get the output from your initial solution, i.e. `lapply(X = my_list, FUN = invertfun)`.

That is, instead of modifying the `list` *in place* the latter solutions *replace*  the `list` elements with new `vector`s.